# How to add '00' before "customer id" column (INT datatype) where customer id of six digits and seven digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Example 1: for `customer id = 1420730` (7 digits), we should show `01420730`

Example 2: for `customer id = 999999` (6 digits), we should show `00999999`

Note: `Customer id` is of `INT` datatype, it should remain an `INT` datatype only after doing the modification

[Error Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT73v.png)

Comment: This sounds more like a job for your application presentation layer.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages, don't link to a screen shot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More complicated but I shy away from `FORMAT()` because the [CLR overhead can be significant](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000' + CONVERT(varchar(11), [Customer id]), 8)
  FROM dbo.tablename;
```

But it begs the question ... what are you going to do when you're on the front page of hacker news and you get 99 million more users? Or you have to change to `bigint`?

- Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ccf1e242bfc575aa3c259a0f78a2bbb)

This can be persisted (but more often than not, people want a [persisted column for the wrong reasons](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns)):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tablename
(
  [Customer id] int,
  PaddedCustomerID AS 
      (CONVERT(char(8), 
       RIGHT('0000000' + CONVERT(varchar(11), [Customer id]), 8))) 
       PERSISTED
);
```

- Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=679d9b1ef0396e495dd9ee581458f930)

In both cases, though, there is *no possible way* for SQL Server to consider this padded number an integer. The only way you can keep those 0s there is to store it as a string. This presentation formatting is something that is much better handled at the presentation layer where the values are presented - there is little to gain by storing them this way (persisted or not).

If persisting this column is a requirement, it should be mentioned in your question. It's not fair to change requirements especially when users have already solved the problem as stated. [Please read about chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `format()`:

```
select format(customerid, '0000000')
```

Note that the result is a string, not a number.  Numbers don't have leading zeros.

Comment: But what to do if I want to keep customer id as int keeping "00" zeros as prefix to customer id

Comment: THen you can not do it. Integer has no leading zeroes PER DEFINITION - those are something you do on the output formatting. It is not part of the value stored, it is part of how you present it. I.e. normally in the application layer.

Comment: FORMAT is the only non-deterministic function of built-in string functions. Hence, it cannot be committed to the database using PERSISTED.

Comment: Note: non-deterministic function is one whose value can change with time. ex- GETDATE() function values changes with date , hence a non-deterministic function.

Comment: @Rohan why are you going on and on about deterministic and non-deterministic functions? Is persisting the column a requirement? If so, why? And why isn't this requirement mentioned in your question? What do you think you gain by persisting the column?